# NGRX entity adapter - how to update/upsert many nested properties

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I am trying to update many entities using `adapter.updateMany()`.

I have `Groups` entity that looks like this (There are multiple groups with multiple children):

[image]

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 222,
      "width": null,
      "height": null,
      ...multipleOtherProperties
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to update `child` width and height inside the group with:

```js
const groups = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 222,
        "groupId": 0,
        "width": 400,
        "height": 368.28125
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But when I use:

```js
on(GroupsActions.updateGroups, (state, { groups }) =>
  adapter.updateMany(groups, state)
)
```

Nothing is happening and when I change `updateMany` to `upsertMany`

```js
on(GroupsActions.updateGroups, (state, { groups }) =>
  adapter.upsertMany(groups, state)
)
```

Children are replaced and I am losing all the properties which are not part of the update.
How to update the properties of children without removing all other properties?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think the adapter does not provide such functionality. You would have to alter the state manually

Comment: In the meantime, I was trying to create solution and I tested `adapter.updateOne` with partial changes like this: `adapter.updateOne({id, changes: { children: changes }}, state)` and it works like expected but I cant translate this into `updateMany`